# Mongo DB connection through JNDI - Mongo 3.4

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, jndi

I am trying to use mongodb client through the JNDI and my container is tomcat.

Install guide of Mongo 3.4 says preferred artifact for new applications is mongodb-driver.

But the JNDI page 'In a Tomcat installation, copy the mongo-java-driver jar file into the lib directory.'

I could not understand why so?

Comment: Please clarify your details

Comment: jars and dependent jars which mongodb-driver uses are bson-3.4.2, mongodb-driver-3.4.2 and mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2 . Now why should I use mongo-java-driver specifically in tomcat. Can't I use only three jars mentioned earlier?